# Generalized forces in Richard Fitzpatrick's Newtonian Dynamics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation

In Richard Fitzpatrick's [*Newtonian Dynamics*](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newton.pdf), page 128, generalized forces are defined as

\begin{equation} \tag{9.6}
  Q_i = \sum_{j=1}^{\mathcal{F}} f_j \cdot \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial q_i}.
\end{equation}

Here, $q_i$ are generalized coordinates, $x_j$ are Cartesian coordinates, and $f_j$ are the Cartesian components of forces acting on particles.

He proceeds to say that in conservative systems

\begin{equation} \tag{9.7}
  f_j = - \frac{\partial U}{\partial x_j}
\end{equation}

and concludes that

\begin{equation} \tag{9.8}
  Q_i = -\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_i}.
\end{equation}

---

I can see how the $\partial x_j$ cancel each other out, but what happened to the sum from equation 9.6? Shouldn't there be a constant factor of $\mathcal{F}$ in equation 9.8?

Comment: Multivariate chain rule removes the j index

Answer (score 2):

$$Q_i = \sum_{j=1}^{\mathcal{F}} f_j \cdot \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial q_i}$$
$$\implies Q_i = -\sum_{j=1}^{\mathcal{F}} \frac{\partial U}{\partial x_j} \cdot \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial q_i}$$
$$\implies Q_i = -\sum_{j=1}^{\mathcal{F}} \frac{\partial U}{\partial x_j} \cdot \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial q_i}$$
$$\implies Q_i = - \frac{\partial U}{\partial x_1} \cdot \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial q_i} - \frac{\partial U}{\partial x_2} \cdot \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial q_i} - \frac{\partial U}{\partial x_3} \cdot \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial q_i} -\ldots   $$
$$\implies Q_i = - \frac{\partial U}{\partial q_i}$$

Note that, for any $j$, $$\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_j} \cdot \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial q_i}\not =\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_i}$$

According to multivariate calculus, the $x_i$'s represent the components of U along those directions and hence the sum is the contribution of those components of U in n-dimensional space.

Comment: The last step, where you conclude that indeed $Q_i=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_i}$ doesn't seem any clearer to me than in the original work. Can you elaborate on how to simplify the equation in this step?

Answer (score 1):

The numerator and denominator in partial derivatives don't cancel out simply. Keep that in your mind!
You should recall the *chain rule* in partial derivatives.

The formal answer to you question may be:

If $U=U(x_1,\cdots,x_f)$, and each $x_f$ is a function of generalized coordinates $(q_1,\cdots,q_g)$, the potential could be expressed as follows

$$U=U[x_1(q_1,\cdots,q_g),\cdots,x_f(q_1,\cdots,q_g)]$$

then
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_i}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial q_i}+\cdots+\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_f}\frac{\partial x_f}{\partial q_i}$$

More detailedly, the total derivative of $U$ is 
$$d U=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_1}dx_1+\cdots+\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_f}dx_f$$
so you must consider every $x_i$ when you want to differentiate $U$ with $q_i$ as other $q$ except $q_i$ fixed.

At the end of the answer, I recommend to use Jacobian in the partial derivatives when you have to cope with so many coordiantes. It will be clearer.